# Dynamically create elements and bind them to a List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dynamic, mvvm

I have a `ObservableCollection<Class1>` where `Class1` contains `x` and `y` positions as properties. The list can be of any size. I have a ViewModel that exposes the collection as a property. In my view, I want to generate a list of elements based on the collection and then set their x and y positions based on the Class1 Object's properties.

How can I do this? I know I can easily bind a collection control (like List View) to the Collection easily. But I need to bind it and the elements use the x, y property to position themselves on the canvas. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Canvas as your ItemsPanel in the ItemsControl, and then bind the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left properties on the ItemContainerStyle to the X and Y properties:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: +1 This seems very promising. Unfortunately, I can't try it out till later today. I'll try it out and then post something back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a [Collection View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) or something similar to achieve this.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damián